# Angular 2 : add hyphen after every 4 digit in input , card number input

Tags: angular, input, credit-card

i need to add an hyphen after every 4 digit i enter, i am getting this in the console , how can i can achieve this to change in the input in angular 2

Code i used given below
**.ts**

```
mychange(val){
  var self = this;
  var chIbn = self.storeData.iban_no.split("-").join("");
  if (chIbn.length > 0) {
   chIbn = chIbn.match(new RegExp('.{1,4}', 'g')).join("-");
 }
 console.log(chIbn);
 self.storeData.iban_no = chIbn;
}
```

**Html**

```
 <input type="text" name="din" (ngModelChange)="mychange($event)"  class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="storeData.iban_no"   required>
```

**Console**

[image]

**input**

[image]

need that hyphen value in input itself

Comment: try [value] = "mychange($event)" in Input tag.

Comment: try my updated method as given in my answer it should work for you

Comment: let me know that worked for you or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do changes as below

```
<input type="text" name="din" (ngModelChange)="mychange($event)"  
class="form-control" [ngModel]="iban_no"   required>
```

you don't need `[(ngModel)]` just keep `[ngModel]` as you are taking care of change event and from method do like this, you don't need `self` in angular `this` will be okay.

```
  mychange(val) {
    const self = this;
    let chIbn = val.split('-').join('');
    if (chIbn.length > 0) {
      chIbn = chIbn.match(new RegExp('.{1,4}', 'g')).join('-');
    }
    console.log(chIbn);
    this.iban_no = chIbn;
  }
```

there is issue in your method too, you need to use `val` instead of property directly as you are trying to modify `val` as assigning value to property.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, But there is no change in the input field

Comment: @AashiqRathnadas - check my update its working for me

Comment: Tried this, Still in input field there is no change

Comment: that must work...crate filed locally in your component and have try

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167381/discussion-between-aashiq-rathnadas-and-pranay-rana).

Comment: @AashiqRathnadas - hi dont have access to chat room right now ..can try to talk tomorrow if you want

Comment: hi, How can i change the pattern to 1111-11111111 , hyphen only at first 4th digit

Answer (score 0):

Create a directive to achieve this.

You can use the `HostBinding` feature to get the element to which the directive is attached to and retrieve the value of the element and do your manipulations to the value.