# Add space after every 4th digit in credit card input

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I need to add a space after every 4th digit I enter, I am getting this in the console, how can I can achieve this to change in the input in Angular 5.

Code I used given below .ts

```ts
  mychange(val) {
    const self = this;
    let chIbn = val.split(' ').join('');
    if (chIbn.length > 0) {
      chIbn = chIbn.match(new RegExp('.{1,4}', 'g')).join(' ');
    }
    console.log(chIbn);
    this.id = chIbn;
  }
```

HTML

```html
<input class="customerno" (ngModelChange)="mychange($event)" [formControl]="inputFormControl" (keydown.backspace)="onKeydown($event)" maxlength="{{digit}}" (keyup)="RestrictNumber($event)" type="tel" matInput [(ngModel)]="id" placeholder="Customer No. ">
```

Console:

```
1
11
111
1111
1111 1
1111 11
1111 111
1111 1111
1111 1111 1
1111 1111 11
1111 1111 111
1111 1111 1111
```

[image]

I adapted it from [Angular 2 : add hyphen after every 4 digit in input , card number input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49421414/angular-2-add-hyphen-after-every-4-digit-in-input-card-number-input). but I changed the hypen to a space.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would recommend to check out this Directive

```
import { Directive, HostListener, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[credit-card]'
})
export class CreditCardDirective {

@HostListener('input', ['$event'])
  onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    const input = event.target as HTMLInputElement;

    let trimmed = input.value.replace(/\s+/g, '');
    if (trimmed.length > 16) {
      trimmed = trimmed.substr(0, 16);
    }

    let numbers = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < trimmed.length; i += 4) {
      numbers.push(trimmed.substr(i, 4));
    }

    input.value = numbers.join(' ');

  }
}
```

and use in your `html` template as

```
<input type="text" credit-card>
```

Here is the
[source code](https://github.com/UltimateAngular/angular-pro-src/tree/master/23-host-listeners/app)

**UPDATE:** (10/10/2019)
Input type should be only `text` (default type)

Comment: Note: this doesn't work if your input is `type="number"`. If you use it on a `number` input, you will get a `The specified value "0000 0" is not a valid number. The value must match to the following regular expression: -?(\d+|\d+\.\d+|\.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?` error from your directive, when you get past the first set of 4 digits, and the input will reset to empty.

Comment: @Coffee-Tea -- no problem. Just as an aside to your edit: I found this directive *does* work with other input types, not **only** `text`. It won't work with `number`, as a number input with spaces is invalid, full stop. As a workaround for my scenario, where I needed leading 0s at the start of the number, using spaces, and I wanted to display a numeric keyboard on mobile devices - I used `tel` input type (with a number/space -only regex pattern); and it works fine for me. I do also believe it will work with other input types with flexibility, for example `search` and also for `textarea`s.

Comment: I went with `tel` in my solution below, and that seems to be working well.

Answer (score 3):

**Don't forget to handle Backspace, Cursor Position, and American Express**

I had to handle some extra complexity, but it's likely what many people will confront when developing this. We need to consider use of the `Backspace` key and arrow keys when rewriting the input value. There is also American Express numbers to consider, which are not simply 4-4-4-4 numbers.

Here's how I did it in a component using a template reference variable and cursor position detection. (No need for a custom directive if you only have one component that is taking credit card numbers, which is often the case.)

To handle `Backspace` and cursor arrow keys, we have to store the original cursor position and restore it after editing from a spot anywhere other than the end of the string.

To enable handling of American Express, I use a variable called `partitions` to store the 4-6-5 spacing format for Amex and the 4-4-4-4 spacing format for all other cards. We loop `partitions` as we add spaces.

```
  /* Insert spaces to make CC number more legible */
  cardNumberSpacing() {
    const input = this.ccNumberField.nativeElement;
    const { selectionStart } = input;
    const { cardNumber } = this.paymentForm.controls;

    let trimmedCardNum = cardNumber.value.replace(/\s+/g, '');

    if (trimmedCardNum.length > 16) {
      trimmedCardNum = trimmedCardNum.substr(0, 16);
    }

     /* Handle American Express 4-6-5 spacing format */
    const partitions = trimmedCardNum.startsWith('34') || trimmedCardNum.startsWith('37') 
                       ? [4,6,5] 
                       : [4,4,4,4];

    const numbers = [];
    let position = 0;
    partitions.forEach(partition => {
      const part = trimmedCardNum.substr(position, partition);
      if (part) numbers.push(part);
      position += partition;
    })

    cardNumber.setValue(numbers.join(' '));

    /* Handle caret position if user edits the number later */
    if (selectionStart < cardNumber.value.length - 1) {
      input.setSelectionRange(selectionStart, selectionStart, 'none');
    }
  }
```

If you have a routine of your own to detect American Express numbers, use it. What I'm using here simply examines the first two digits and compares them to [PAN/IIN standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_card_number).

Higher in your component, ensure you have the right imports:

```
import { ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
```

And:

```
  @ViewChild('ccNumber') ccNumberField: ElementRef;
```

And when you set up your form controls, do something like this so that spaces can be included in your regex pattern:

```
this.paymentForm = this.fb.group({
  cardNumber: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[ 0-9]*$';), Validators.minLength(17)]]
})
```

And finally, in your template, configure your element like this:

```
    <input maxlength="20"
        formControlName="cardNumber"
        type="tel"
        #ccNumber
        (keyup)="cardNumberSpacing()">
```

You should be good to go!